# PHP cURL string to json api

Tags: php, json, curl

i am trying to get some data as json or array format from CURL in php.
After 3 CURL request i get to the page from there i want to fetch the data.

The data is in the old school html format with tables the tr and td mess

I get the data back from CURL as string, how can i make it parse-able so i can work with it and insert it into a data base.

here is the cURL code:

```
$page_url = "somedomain.com/third/request";
$postfields2 = array();
$postfields2['field'] = "value1";
$postfields2['feild2'] = "value2";

$ch2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $fb_page_url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$ret2 = curl_exec($ch2); **//data returned here is string checked using gettype()**

curl_close($ch2);
```

How do i go about extracting the data form the $ret2 variable which is a string.

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: if it's html, that means it's also XML, since html is a subset of XML, so, if you're feeling lazy, this would work: `$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($HTML_GOES_HERE)),TRUE);`

Comment: tried it..it gives this Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object ....i have included the file but still not able to find the find() function

Comment: html is not valid so the simplexml_load_string gives this ->parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined

Comment: @AgeDeO http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net has file_get_html() method that takes url and returns object if i pass string to it  it fails

Comment: found another function which is not mentioned in the doc str_get_html() this works with string data